# Is the classpath really not accessible to Java modules?

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system

I am a little confused about the supposed behavior that Java 9 modules should have. In the O'Reilly's *Java 9 Modularity*, I've read the statement:

> Modules cannot read the classpath, so our module can’t access types on
> the classpath, as illustrated in Figure 8-1.
>
> ...
>
> The unnamed module exports all code on the classpath and reads all
> other modules. There is a big restriction, however: the unnamed module
> itself is readable only from automatic modules!

However, trying to solve an issue on Eclipse (The maven dependencies are at classpath instead of module path), I've noted that my application's launcher settings conflicts with what I've read. Here's the command line it executes:

```
/opt/jdk-16+36/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-p /home/lgmonezi/workspace/my.test/target/classes
-classpath /home/lgmonezi/.m2/repository/org/hsqldb/hsqldb/2.6.0/hsqldb-2.6.0.jar
-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
-m my.test/net.lgmonezi.test.main.FileNode
```

Although a module-info.java is present, the only external dependency that the application have is the hsqldb-2.6.0 jar. But it's in the classpath, and being accessed by an explicit module, not an automatic one. The code runs fine. Shouldn't it be throwing exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> our module can’t **access** types on the classpath

Your code is not using any of the [HSQLDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSQLDB) classes (directly), so there is no *access* checks in play.

The [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) being on the classpath makes it auto-register an implementation of the [`java.sql.Driver`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html) interface with the [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) framework via the [service-provider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface) loading mechanism. (See [JDBC 4 specification](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221), section 9.2.1)

Other than that auto-register process, no code (yours or framework) "accesses" any of the HSQLDB code directly. It's all done through interfaces.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you. I forgot about SPI. I've tested with another library (json.org), which does not use SPI and eclipse put it right on the module-path. Now I'll try to find out why the hsqldb driver is going to the classpath at the first place, since it is a modular jar. Again, thank you!